# Hiding nib file in target application package and package organization issue

Tags: xcode, macos, build, release

When I create an project of OS X normally, and then build it. When I click "Show Package Contents" on the target app, in its ./Contents/Resources directory, all resources (nib files, image files, sound files, etc) are put together.

---

Now there are **several questions**:

**<1>** Can I hide my nib files from user to keep the completeness of it?

**<2>** This may similar with the first one: can I package other resource files or encrypted them in on or several target file so that user could not modify them? Just like Windows applications do?

**<3>** Can I organize my resources by directory in target package content? For example, if I show the package content of Firefox, all files are organized pretty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) .nib files are readonly by default in XCode 4, the user cannot view or edit them.

2) Binary encryption can be done perhaps adopting from iOS to osx: [Executable encryption check anti piracy measure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038143/executable-encryption-check-anti-piracy-measure)

3) Organization can be done via drag and drop of folders: Create your folder in the filesystem, then drag it to the resource folder in XCode. In the following dialog select create folder reference for any added folder. The folder should be blue. This folder is copied to your bundle with its contents.

Comment: Thanks! And further question: In 3), The folders added in that way would be automatically placed under "Resource" directory. Can I specify this path?

Comment: Oops, another question risen. Please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533227/can-i-put-all-nib-files-together-in-another-folder-in-target-application-package).