# Can I put all nib files together in another folder in target application package?

Tags: xcode, macos, compilation

I tried putting all xib files together in a folder in my project. And then I add this folder into the Xcode project, Hoping that Xcode may recognized them and put them in the directory I want in target package.

But when I ran the target, the console(NSLog) told me that the nib file could not be found.

I looked into the directory, there are xib files there instead of nib file.

Here comes the question mentioned in the title. Can I achieve that?

---

Here is the scene:

I built the project. Then Xcode convert xib files into nib ones then put them in the "Resources" directory. As **all** resource files (including these nib files) are put together under this folder, it looks messy.

What I wanted to do is put all these resource in different folder automatically after the building was done. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way this is possible, except in localization (see auto-created folder structure): https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/conceptual/cfbundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW7

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

1. select all of the XIB files
2. change the file type to something else
3. then set the file type BACK to the default type (IB CocoaTouch XIB)
4. de-select all of the files
5. clean the project, delete the previous version(s) from the simulator(s)
6. build the project

now it should contain contain only NIBs, no XIBs.

Comment: Wow, that was too complicated. I have an idea: add a shell command to move("mv" command) all nib files to the directory I specified as soon as build success. But I do not know how to use command line tool... :(

Comment: @AndrewChang - well isn't the problem you don't have the .nib files, but instead .xib; how would you move what you don't have?

Comment: Nope. Sorry for my bad description. I have updated my question. Is it clearer?

Comment: @AndrewChang, oh now you tell me! [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4425148/1204467) looks to be what you're looking to do i think.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the answer you posted was talking about organizing file in PROJECT instead of built target package. But still, it helps, in another field.